# Add extra column to new order product select

Tags: magento2, orders

I want to add extra column to search product under new order. How do I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. add attribute to the product. For example I add Barcode attribute.
2. Edit:

> /app/code/Magento/Sales/Block/Adminhtml/Order/Create/Search/Grid.php

Add the filter, for example I add Barcode filter:

```
$this->addColumn('barcode', ['header' => __('Barcode'), 'index' => 'barcode']);
```

3.Run:

```
rm -rf var/page_cache/*
rm -rf var/cache/*
rm -rf generated/*
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*
rm -rf pub/static/*

php  bin/magento  setup:upgrade;
php  bin/magento setup:di:compile;
php  bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f;
```